# Azure Data Factory or Azure Function

Tags: architecture, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-files

We have a requirement where we need to pull files from an external entity. We primarily want to use Azure Cloud based solution (external entity is not on Azure). One approach is to use Azure Datafactory for pulling the file and another is to use Azure Functions.

Working considerations:
File size: 200 KB to 500 KB
Generation frequency:  2K to 10K.
Polling frequency: Every 5 minutes.
Fault tolerance: No file should be lost

Which of the two, ADF or AF will be a better fit?

Additionally will Azure Files be a good option if we change from Pull to Push?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use azure data factory. Of course azure function can achieve what you want, but azure data factory is designed to do data process, so it will be more quickly than azure function.